# What is the "workflow," like when managing a custom GIT fork?

Tags: git

I'm thinking of creating a custom fork of a program to customize and fit my day-to-day uses a bit more, and was wondering how I would manage the fork to keep up to date with bug fixes and stuff in the original repository.

To keep things simple let's use a fictional piece of software, let's call it "Fruit Organizer," and pretend it's a program that lets you create and organize detailed lists of different types of fruit.

---

Now, this program is great and has a lot of features and algorithms that are fast and useful for creating, organizing, and getting information on all different types of fruit. Thing is, in my day job I work only with apples, but lots of different types of apples. Since this is the case, I make a custom fork with the following changes:

1. I delete all of the code that has to do specifically with other fruits such as bananas, oranges, etc. and modify the remaining code to work without it.
2. I modify the existing code so that all text references only refer to apples, and rename the program to "Apple Organizer."
3. I add a bunch of functions and features that specifically deal with apples, to make dealing with apples easier.

---

Now obviously this is a worst-case-scenario for a fork, but I'm curious pulling from upstream would work in the different cases.

1. The upstream repository updates all the banana algorithms to be much more efficient. Since this code no longer exists in my repository, what happens when I merge?
2. Upstream fixes a bunch of spelling errors in the text strings. Thing is, I already changed all of the text strings in the program to reference apples so almost none of the original text is there anymore. Is my text replaced with theirs?
3. When I added my custom functions I obviously had to change some references to point to my custom functions where things like `getFruit()` instead calls `getAllApples()`. If upstream adds some new functions themselves that change these references, will their references replace my references? Also if they add new functions (even if they are irrelevant such as `getBananas()`) I assume those will be just be added to the program correct?

How do I manage this? Is the solution just to be extremely careful and cherry-pick each and every commit to make sure it applies to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the scenario's you describe, when you pull the changes from upstream, git will see that both you and upstream independently made changes to the same (portions of) files and will indicate that there is a merge conflict.

Then it is up to you to inspect each location that is indicated to have a conflict and resolve the conflict before you can merge the two branches.

With the extent of the changes you mentioned, this conflict resolution can be a tedious job, but is fairly straightforward. In most cases, you probably want to take your version of the conflicting lines, but still it is good to check that upstream did not change anything there that could also be relevant for you.

You can ease the conflict resolution by cherry-picking and ignoring those commits that contain changes that are completely irrelevant for you.

Comment: This is kind of what I assumed it would be, but was wondering if Git would intelligently handle it in some way. Thanks for the answer

Comment: The intelligence if git is in accurately detecting which parts of a file have changed, even across renaming files and big changes between the unchanged parts. Deciding on what to do with conflicting changes still requires understanding of what is actually written there, which git doesn't have.